# AWS SQL Server Read Replicas - publish from private server

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, database-replication

Is is possible to use AWS RDS for SQL Server as the destination / target for a read replica?

I have a database that runs on a private MS SQL instance in my data centre and I would like to publish a set of tables to an AWS SQL Server instance so that I can use that instance, and possibly others, to speed up read-only queries.

I know that AWS has restrictions and I wanted to know if the necessary infrastructure exists that would allow me to run a publisher and distributor within my data centre and target an AWS SQL Server database?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with Cloudbasic's RDS SQL Server HADR tool available on the AWS Marketplace: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00OU0PE5M

Launch it in the same AWS VPC as your RDS SQL Server instance. In the quick setup, make sure to select SQL Server-to-SQL Server replication (as the tool also streams data from SQL Server to Redshift and S3 data lakes). Then to limit publishing to a subset of tables, after testing connections go to advanced settings, exclude tables you do not want to be published.